# Flattening JSON lines arrays with JQ

Tags: json, jq

I can write

```
> echo '{"a": "arbiter", "b": "brisk"}{"a": "astound", "b": "bistro"}' | jq '.a, .b'
"arbiter"
"brisk"
"astound"
"bistro"
```

but if I do

```
> echo '{"a": "arbiter", "b": "brisk", "c": ["cloak", "conceal"]} {"a": "astound", "b": "bistro", "c": ["confer", "consider"]}' | jq '.a, .b, .c'
```

I get

```
"arbiter"
"brisk"
[
    "cloak",
    "conceal"
]
"astound"
"bistro"
[
    "confer",
    "consider"
]
```

How do I flatten the `c` arrays to get instead

```
"arbiter"
"brisk"
"cloak",
"conceal"
"astound"
"bistro"
"confer",
"consider"
```

**Update**

Since null safety is quite fashionable in several modern languages (and justifiably so), it is perhaps fitting to suppose that the question as asked above was incomplete. It's necessary to know how to handle the absence of a value.

If one of the values is `null`,

```
> echo '{"b": "brisk"}{"a": "astound", "b": "bistro"}' | jq '.a, .b'
```

we get a null in the output

```
null
"brisk"
"astound"
"bistro"
```

That may well be what we want. We could add a second step in the pipeline (watching out not to exclude `"null"`), but it's cleaner if `jq` itself excludes `null`s. Just writing `select(.a != null)` does the trick, but introduces a `{}` level. What is the right way to discard `null`s from within `jq`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `jq` expression

```
[.a, .b, .c]
```

extracts all the elements that we want from the input objects, and places them in an array.  Some of these elements may be arrays, so we need to flatten all elements:

```
[.a, .b, .c] | flatten
```

For the input object

```json
{
  "a": "arbiter",
  "b": "brisk",
  "c": [
    "cloak",
    "conceal"
  ]
}
```

this generates the array

```json
[
  "arbiter",
  "brisk",
  "cloak",
  "conceal"
]
```

and you'll get a similar but separate array from your second object.

To merge these two arrays into one, we may simply pass the data through `.[]`, but a shortcut way of writing `flatten | .[]` is `flatten[]`.  Using this, we arrive at

```
[.a, .b, .c] | flatten[]
```

Summary:

```bsh
echo '...as in the question...' |
jq '[.a, .b, .c] | flatten[]'
```

If you additionally want to weed out any `null` values, filter through `select(. != null)`, or extract the values using `[.a//empty,.b//empty,.c//emtpy]`, or filter through `map(.//empty)` before `flatten[]`.

---

As a comment:  Your input JSON is created using a simple `echo` in the question.  However, to properly create JSON on the command line, consider using a tool like `jo`, which will additionally encode your data appropriately for inclusion in a JSON document:

Your second example JSON could be created using the two `jo` invocations

```
jo a=arbiter b=brisk  'c[]'=cloak  'c[]'=conceal
jo a=astound b=bistro 'c[]'=confer 'c[]'=consider
```

Answer (score 2):

*This answer addresses the question before the update.*

Ok, that was rather trivial. No need for Python's delightful JSON library, nor even to lower the floor with the genericity of awk or sed for this one. It's enough to write:

```
> echo '{"a": "arbiter", "b": "brisk", "c": ["cloak", "conceal"]} {"a": "astound", "b": "bistro", "c": ["confer", "consider"]}' | jq '.a, .b, .c[]'
```

and we get:

```
"arbiter"
"brisk"
"cloak"
"conceal"
"astound"
"bistro"
"confer"
"consider"
```

Comment: or `... | jq 'flatten[]'`

Comment: @Freddy Neat, but if in addition to `a/b/c` we also had, say, `timestamp` that we wanted to ignore, that would capture it. Other hints along the line you suggest?

Comment: You could remove the timestamps first, e.g. `... | jq 'del(.timestamp) | flatten[]'`.

Comment: @Freddy that's definitely worth an answer

Comment: Well, I made my answer insufficient by making the question slightly harder. Take a look and tell me. I think the pair of questions should always arise together, not as two separate questions. And of course the question is open again.